# Suspicious memory leak when using getopt lib in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, c, api, memory-leaks, getopt

[image: Memory Usage and Thread Usage monitor]

I am posting this post on behalf of my college.

He found a suspicious memory leak when using the handle_option (MySQL getopt lib) to read config file (/etc/my.cnf)

He execute the Source code below after malloc host_name, user name:

```
char* host_name;
char* user_name;

struct my_option mysql_confgs[] = 
{
  {"host", "h", "MySQL Server", (uchar**) & host_name, NULL, NULL, GET_STR, 
REQUIRED_ARG, 0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {"user", "u", "userID", "h",(uchar**) & user_name, NULL, NULL, GET_STR, 
REQUIRED_ARG, 0,0,0,0,0,0}
}

handle_options(&argc, &argv, mysql_configs, aux_config_reader);
```

He mention about the method above is using Error(Segment) instead of using free(host_name) and free(user_name)? So this is the possible reason of causing memory leakage?

Well.. I have zero basic on MySQL, so I might not able to delivery 100% of the problem description. So, feel free to query on this and I will update the details of problem descriptions as per the query.

My college is having language barrier so I am posting on behalf of him.

Valgrind Report:

```
480 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 26 of 43
at 0x4A068FE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
by 0x33E4E293C1: my_malloc (in /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0)
by 0x33E4E2C974: alloc_root (in /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0)
by 0x33E4E2E620: ??? (in /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0)
by 0x33E4E2F838: my_load_defaults (in /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0)
by 0x408BF1: MS_MYSQL_init (MS_MYSQL_O.h:109)
by 0x438A39: main_proc (AccLab.c:221)
by 0x437F8A: main (AccLab.c:67)

75,840 bytes in 158 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 41 of 43
at 0x4A068FE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
by 0x33E4E293C1: my_malloc (in /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0)
by 0x33E4E2C974: alloc_root (in /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0)
by 0x33E4E2E620: ??? (in /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0)
by 0x33E4E2F838: my_load_defaults (in /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0)
by 0x408BF1: MS_MYSQL_init (MS_MYSQL_O.h:109)
by 0x438A39: main_proc (AccLab.c:221)
by 0x437F8A: main (AccLab.c:67)
```

LEAK SUMMARY:

```
definitely lost: 75,840 bytes in 158 blocks
indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
possibly lost: 2,304 bytes in 7 blocks
still reachable: 9,675,408 bytes in 2,387 blocks
suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes

For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
ERROR SUMMARY: 8 errors from 8 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to change host_name and user_name to `uchar *` to avoid the not-very-well-defined cast from `char **` to `uchar **`.

Comment: Have you considered using valgrind to determine which block of memory is leaking?

Comment: Ivalue, I have just updated the post. We run the Valgrind and check the memory leak. In fact, this is the first time we use Valgrind, so how to interpret the Valgrind report from the above?

Answer (score 0):

Put `printf("user_name: %p; host_name: %p\n", (void *) user_name, (void *) host_name);` before and after the call to handle_options and run your code. Do the additional two lines printed as a result differ from each other? If so, your diagnosis is correct and user_name and host_name are changed by handle_options, and perhaps using a malloc'd pointer is unsuitable for this function.

If not, your diagnosis is incorrect and the memory leak lies elsewhere. You'd want to look at the source code for MS_MYSQL_init, main_proc and main, in that order, which are the three functions listed by valgrind from your project. Let me know if you need my help...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the combination of allocating memory to the pointer `my_option.value` is pointing to along with the use of `GET_STR` is leading to leaking what had been allocated to `my_option.value`, as `GET_PTR` initalises what `my_option.value` is pointing to, to point right to somewhere into what had been passed as `argv` to `handle_options`, without freeing what the value `my_option.value` is pointing, previously pointed to.

To get around this, either do not allocate any memory to what `my_option.value` is pointing to prior to passing it to `handle_options` or  allocate it using `my_alloc()` and use `GET_PTR_ALLOC` as value type, as `GET_PTR_ALLOC` implies a call to `my_free()` on what `my_option.value` is pointing to prior to re-initialising what it is pointing to.

---

Just out of curiosity: What is `uchar`, and why do you cast to `uchar **` and not to `void *`, the type of `my_option.value`?

---

Also this

```
"user", "u", "userID", "h",(uchar**) & user_name ...
```

should read

```
"user", "u", "userID", (uchar**) & user_name ...
```

shouldn't it?